# Copy just dates, not the formulas behind it from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy just data and not the formulas behind it from the sheet "Data" into the sheet "Report".

```
Sub CopyValueDown() 

Dim lRow As Integer
    lRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow > 1 Then 
        Sheets("Report").Range("A1:H1").AutoFill _
                  Destination:=Range("A1:H" & lRow)
    end if
End Sub
```

It says that the AutoFill-Methode does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quote the exact error message.

Comment: Where are you copying from `Data` to `Report`?  This code finds the last row in column A on the `Data` sheet and if it's more than one it fills the `Report` sheet down from `A1:H1` to the last row found on the `Data` sheet.  It doesn't copy anything over from the `Data` sheet - if A1:H1 is blank it will just fill blank cells down.  **E.g.** Place a _1_ in `Data!A11` and a _3_ in `Report!H1` and `H1:H11` will fill with _3, 4, 5....13_

Comment: Thanks! I got it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `.AutoFill`, but `.FillDown`. Give it a try like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    If lrow > 1 Then
        Range("A1:H" & lrow).FillDown
    End If
End Sub
```